# find particular solution $y''+y'+4y=t^2+(2t+3)(1+cos(t))$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

find particular solution $y''+y'+4y=t^2+(2t+3)(1+Cos(t))$

I'm looking for a way to make the right side less complicated or if there is any trick.

What I would do is break it into two parts and add the solutions to obtain the particular solution.

So after expanding, I obtain:

$y''+y'+4y=t^2+(2t+3)(1+Cos(t))$

$y''+y'+4y=t^2+2t+3+2tCos(t)+3cos(t))$

Since our right hand side contains cosine, we want the real part. Therefore, I would break into:

$y''+y'+4y=t^2+2t+3$

$y''+y'+4y=2tCos(t)+3cos(t)$

Find each particular solution $\psi_{1}$ and $\psi_{2}$ and add them together to get the particular solution $\psi$.
Do I seem to be headed on the right track?

Comment: This looks good to me ! Go ahead.